# Google Chrome Extension chrome.storage.sync instead of LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm having trouble understanding Google's storage.sync and storage.local.

I'm working on a google chrome extension that currently uses LocalStorage.
There's this snippet of code that renders the data.

```
var data = (localStorage.getItem('todoList')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoList')):{
    todo: [],
    completed: []
};
```

and this snippet of code that updates it

```
function dataObjectUpdated() {
   localStorage.setItem('todoList', JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

I'm failing to understand how a method of localStorage (getItem and setItem) can be replaced with what seems to be a function call that I must pass a key,value pair to.

> Example of Sync storage from Chrome Extension API

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({key: value}, function() {
      console.log('Value is set to ' + value);
    });
```

Sorry i'm not too good with javascript :)

Here's what i've tried to replace the first snippet

```
var data = (chrome.storage.sync.get(['todoList'])) ? JSON.parse(chrome.storage.sync.get(['todoList'])):{
    todo: [],
    completed: []
};
```

Here's what i've tried to replace the second snippet

```
function dataObjectUpdated() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'todoList': JSON.stringify(data)});
}
```

So after tinkering with this for quite a while I believe that because this is an ASYNC call that my original logic from the first snippet isn't applicable (correct me if i'm wrong)

I'm not entirely sure how to refactor the first snippet to work with this ASYNC api.

Comment: I dont completely understand your question, but-- sessionStorage and localStorage both operate on key value pair. For example: 
sessionStorage.setItem("dogbreed", "pug"); If you run this js command and look in your Chrome Browser> More Tools > Developer Tools > Application Tab SessionStorage, you will see this key/ value pair saved as long as your session is active. I hope this helps in some way!

Comment: @Chris after doing some more searching I did find out that both localStorage and sessionStorage operate on key, value pair.

I think the only issue I might be having is understanding how sync.storage is equivalent to the setItem method in localStorage

Comment: @Chris

Here's what I tried to replace the first snippet of code above. See above for formatted code.